# listview pushing edittext behind the keyboard

Tags: listview, android-layout

I have 2 sections in my activity. One is static with some data and another is a chat section with scrollable list view. As I enter data from `EditText` in `type_message_area` and `listview`'s size increases.listview pushes the `type_message_area` behind the soft keyboard. How can I fix the `type_message_area`control to not go behind the keyboard and listview always sroll upwards.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f1f1f1"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.myapp.application.ConversationActivity">


<!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows. -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
            style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgUserProfile"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:contentDescription="userProfileImage"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imgUserProfile"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgUserProfile"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:ems="12"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"/>

            <View android:id="@+id/separator"
                  android:background="@color/icon_gray"
                  android:layout_below="@id/nameTextView"
                  android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
                  android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                  android:layout_height="2dip"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

<!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
 is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
 TextureView, etc. -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/outLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/msgListView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/separator"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/type_message_area"
                    android:divider="@null"
                    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

                <include
                    layout="@layout/type_message_area"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@id/msgListView"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="bottom" />

            </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Below is `type_message_area.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="bottom"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sendConversationEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColorHint="@color/icon_gray"
    android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
    android:hint="@string/conversation_edit_text_hint" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sendConversationButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/btn_solid_white"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
    android:text="@string/send_conversation"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my scroll on `listview` in `ConversationActivity.java`

```
     ListView msgListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.msgListView);
    //Set autoscroll of listview when a new message arrives
    msgListView.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
    msgListView.setStackFromBottom(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify keyboard behavior on the activity level. See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

You basically have 2 options to fix your problem. Set the `windowSoftInputMode` activity attribute to either:

- `adjustResize`: Resizes your activity to fit the remaining screen real estate. This might cause a problem where the `ListView` is resized and the `EditText` clips out of bound.
- `adjustPan`: Does not resize the activity. It pans the whole activity up and aligns the bottom of the input element with the top of your soft keyboard. This should AFAIK give the desired result. (user always sees what he/she is currently typing)